# Re-opening all video related questions on combined AVP site

Tags: discussion

With the combined Alien vs Predator, er, I mean Audio-Video Production SE now active, I think it's important to re-open all questions related to video that were closed as off-topic previously. I asked my first video-related question and while I saw a whole list of interesting question in 'related', all of them were closed. Can seem unwelcoming to the video editing / production community who'll be coming to the site.

It will be overwhelming for moderators if we start flagging a whole load of questions as needing attention, so is there any other way? I don't currently have enough reputation to vote for reopening questions, for instance.

Comment: Here here. I was looking around for questions to answer and noticed alot of existing video questions that were closed from before.

Comment: ok, the AVP joke is not new to me, but the way you worked it in there was outstanding :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I got most of them reopened.  If you see any more that you think should be reopened please flag them.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you got most of the ones that I noticed.

Comment: I'll open any that I see as well.